# Data Scrapping with JavaScript only using fetch call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, fetch-api

Here I use the fetch() to call the API and then get all the HTML files. Now I want to get the meta tag only i.e `<meta property="og:title"/>`  I tried the following code but it shows the output null. How can I get the meta tag content value with the property that contains the og tags only?

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of your linter. It shows that you have an unused variable `doc`. Why is it unused? Because in the next line, you use `document` instead of `doc`.